# Want to take a suggestion on android NDK

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, thumbnails

In my project i have to use thumbnail of PDF files. I used PDF-Render got some results but they are not robust working on all files , its very size dependent and slow. Since I have only **4 days** to submit my project I was thinking to do the job using some C/C++ Library with NDK. the problem is that **I have no experience with NDK**. Is it possible to get my job done in 4 days. Also if I could know any such C/C++ library. I have good experience with SDK.

Thanks for your time to answer my quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my experience with the NDK I would not recommend trying to use it on such a sophisticated problem with such a short timeline.  By the time you download the NDK, setup all your paths, BTW is this linux or Windoze?, and try integrating it into eclipse you've already got maybe half a day gone.  Let alone the time to find a robust way to deliver your binary with your apk.  It can be done, and there are techniques out there, i.e. setting up an assets folder and copying the binary out of the android package which is kind of nasty.  Also, you'll be cross compiling for the ARM from whatever machine you are using.  The NDK has that pretty well taken care of, but you'll have to find the right gcc in prebuilt or build it yourself.  In closing, although NDK is AWESOME, it does have significant challenges.

Comment: it is windows. It seems quite a long process. I think it wont help if I start with NDK.

Comment: i agree, windows would just make it more difficult anyway.